# why pagination repeats some data again in the next page?

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I'm use pagination to paginate data in page, this data is a photos name `(ex: 11abf76631b0c9daf2284825c3b6ade7.jpg)`.
The problem is showing photos frequently in next pages.
Also total data in database is 30 elements, and here displays 40 elements.

**Page 1**
[image: Page1]
**Page2**
[image: apge2]

**Controller:** `photos_album`

```
$this->load-> library('pagination');
$config['base_url'] = base_url()."admin/photos_album/display";
$config['total_rows'] = $this->photos_album_model->count_all();
$config['per_page'] = 20;
$config['num_links'] = 5;
$config['uri_segment'] = 4;
$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
$config['full_tag_open'] = "<div id='pagination' class='clear'>";
$config['full_tag_close'] = "</div>";
$config['prev_link'] = "<span class='pe-7s-angle-right fontSize_20'></span>";
$config['prev_tag_open'] = "<div id='prev' class='float_right'>";
$config['prev_tag_close'] = "</div><div id='counter'>";
$config['cur_tag_open'] = "<div class='float_right current'>";
$config['cur_tag_close'] = "</div>";
$config['num_tag_open'] = "<span class='float_right'>";
$config['num_tag_close'] = "</span>";
$config['next_link'] = "<span class='pe-7s-angle-left fontSize_20'></span>";
$config['next_tag_open'] = "<div id='next' class='float_right'>";
$config['next_tag_close'] = "</div>";
$config['first_link'] = "";
$config['last_link'] = "";
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
$page = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri-> segment(4) : 0;
$data['db_data'] = $this->photos_album_model->get_all($config["per_page"], $page);
$data['pagination_links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
```

**Model:** `photos_album_model`

```
public function get_all($limit, $start) {
    return $this-> db-> limit($limit, $start)-> get('photo_album');
}

public function count_all() {
    return $this->db->count_all("photo_album");
}
```

**View**

```
<div class="main_block">
   <div class="title"><span class="pe-7s-browser fontSize_18"></span> <h2 class="font_2"></h2></div>
    <div class="content fontSize_18 font_1">
        <div id="images" class="clear gallery clearfix">
            <?php
            if ($db_data->num_rows() > 0) {
                foreach ($db_data->result() as $photo) {
                    ?>
                    <div class="float_right"><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/uploads/<?php echo $photo->image;?>" class="hyperlink" rel="photofly"><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/uploads/thumbs/<?php echo $photo->image;?>" alt="" /></a><div class="tools"> <a href="#"><span class="pe-7s-note editBtn"></span></a><a href="<?php echo base_url() . 'admin/photos_album/delete_processing/' . $photo->photo_id ?>" onclick="return confirm('Do you want to delete this item ?')" ><span class="pe-7s-close-circle delBtn"></span></a></div></div>
                    <?php
                }
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php echo $pagination_links; ?>
</div>
```

Note: my pagination page start from 0 not from 1, and I don't know if this correct or not.

Comment: does the query have an `ORRDER BY`

Comment: @Dagon: No, I did not use `ORRDER BY`.

Comment: well aside from the great answer below by jeroen you should as there is no inherit order in a db.

Answer (score 2):

The reason of problem was very simple.

The problem was in this property

**Change**

```
$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
```

**To**

```
$config['use_page_numbers'] = FALSE;
```

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

You have a mistake in your logic here:

```
$page = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri-> segment(4) : 0;
$data['db_data'] = $this->photos_album_model->get_all($config["per_page"], $page);

...

public function get_all($limit, $start) {
    return $this-> db-> limit( $limit, $start)-> get('photo_album');
}
```

You are sending two parameters to your function: The number of items per page and the page number. However, in your method you treat them like the limit (correct) and the start (wrong).

You would need something like:

```
public function get_all($limit, $page) {
    return $this-> db-> limit($limit, ($page * $limit) )-> get('photo_album');
}
```

You should also add a fixed `ORDER BY` clause to make sure the order on every request is the same.

Comment: I did it, but there is a new problem. the first page contain 20 images, but the next page is empty, note that there are 10 images still does not appear. `public function get_all($limit, $start) {
        return $this->db->limit($limit, ($start * $limit))->order_by('photo_id', 'desc')->get('photo_album');
    }`

Comment: @LionKing Have you checked the values of the variables?

Comment: @LionKing If you want to avoid that and use page 1, 2, etc., just use `( ($page - 1) * $limit )`. Then your page 1 will be the first page, etc.

Comment: @LionKing Instead of `($page * $limit)`

Comment: Thank you for your help. the problem was solved, and the reason of problem was very simple.